# How to detect / find out which SLT version is installed

Tags: slt

In order to create another thread I would like to find out / verify which SLT (SAP Landscape Transformation Server) version is installed on our server.

Can somebody describe the steps to find out the installed version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the top menu choose:

System -> Status... -> Component Button

[image: System Status Window]

Many thanks to Brillion Johns who answered this question on SCN